# React textarea intialstate

Tags: reactjs, textarea

I try to read from a txt file and pass it into inner text for initial content. This is my component everything works fine except {this.state.innerText} and getinitialstate function though

```
var TxtAreaControl = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        var data = initLoadNotes();
         return {
             innerText: data
         }
     },
     saveNotes: function(){
         saveChanges();
     },
     render: function () {
        return (
        <div>
            <textarea id = "txtarea" onBlur={this.saveNotes} rows = "11" columns = "30" >
                {this.state.innerText}
            </textarea>
        </div>
        );
    }
});
```

and the initLoadFunction

```
function initLoadNotes(){
    fs.readFile('./notes.txt', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
          if(err){
              alert("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message);
              return;
          }
          // Change how to handle the file content
          //document.getElementById('txtarea').textContent = data;
          return data;
    });
}
```

How I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I read file async. I change readfile to readfilesync and fixed